# Finding the first element of an array that satisfies a condition using an Async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a rather weird issue.
I wish to find the first element of an array that satisfies a condition but the find function must be marked as async because a promise is needed to perform the search.

Please the code below is just a sample. The real code that performs the asynchronous search is not shown. But the below is exactly similar to what I intend to do within the find function

Here is the sample code below

```
async testForVideo() {
    let media=["sampleMedia.png"];
    let video = media.find(async (x) => await x.includes(".mp4"));
    console.log(`Retrived Video=${video}`);
}
```

To my greatest, the response I keep getting back is this

```
Retrived Video=sampleMedia.png
```

This is so weird. I was expecting `undefined` as the correct result, why is it returning a wrong value instead?

> I was expecting
>
> ```
> Retrived Video=undefined
> ```

Any ideas on why this is the case would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` does not support `async` callbacks so in your case the callback will always return a promise which is `trueish` for the `find` method so it will return the first element of an array.